# Format Prefix of Custom Float Environment entry in Custom List of Figures

Tags: labels, tocloft, newfloat, tocbasic

I am working on a document with complex formatting based on `report` class.

I defined a new List of Figures for Photographs using `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` from `newfloat` package based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292470). I customized the prefix of the entry in the list of figures using `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` from `tocbasic` package based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437194/151425). I got this result:

[image]

The problem is, the prefix in the **List of Photographs** is still **Figure**. I have tried a lot of solutions on many forums but none of them worked. I cannot change the class or packages because it breaks the formatting and create problems. For example, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81784/151425) uses `scrreprt` which I cannot use. I also tried `\newfloat` from `float` package (commented out in the script at the end) based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324003/151425) but I could neither add prefix (Photograph) in the entry in the **List of Photographs** nor customize it, it only shows the number and not the **Figure**/**Photograph**. I also tried to use `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` for `photograph` but it generates errors:

```
Package tocbasic Error: toc style `tocline' needs toc style level.
Package tocbasic Error: toc style `tocline' needs toc entry level.
Package tocbasic Error: toc style `tocline' needs entry indent.
Package tocbasic Error: toc style `tocline' needs entry number width.
```

I used `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` after `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` because `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` internally uses `\listoffigures` so declaring it after toc style entry inherits the formatting. Declaring it above toc style entry doesn't show the prefix.

The result I need is this:

[image]

The simplified version of latex script is attached here. Is there any way I can change the prefix **Figure** to **Photograph** in the **List of Photographs**?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\figureentryformat{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em
]{tocline}{figure}
\newcommand\figureentryformat[2]{\textbf{#1\enspace#2.}\hfill}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lop,
  listname={List of Photographs},
  name=Photograph,
  placement=tp,
  within=chapter,
  chapterlistsgaps=on,
]{photograph}

%\usepackage{float}
%\newfloat{photograph}{tbp}{lop}[chapter]
%\floatname{photograph}{Photograph}
%\newcommand{\listofphotograpsname}{List of Photographs}
%\newcommand{\listofphotographs}{%
%    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listofphotograpsname}
%    \listof{photograph}{\listofphotograpsname}
%}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listofphotographs
\endgroup

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{First dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Second dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{photograph}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{First dummy photo}
\end{photograph}
\begin{photograph}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Second dummy photo}
\end{photograph}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses the package `tocloft` to setup the two lists.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{tocloft} % added <<<<<<<<<<

\newlistof{photograph}{lop}{List of Photograph}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
fileext=lop,
listname={List of Photographs},
%name=Photograph,
placement=tp,
within=chapter,
chapterlistsgaps=on,
]{photograph}


\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\bfseries Figure~} % List of FIgures set up <<<<<<<<
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5ex}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0ex}
\newlength{\figlen}% a pre figure title length
\settowidth{\figlen}{\bfseries\cftfigpresnum} % the word Figure~
\addtolength{\figlen}{\cftfignumwidth}
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{\figlen}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{.}


\renewcommand{\cftphotographpresnum}{\bfseries Photograph~} % List of Photograph set up <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\cftphotographnumwidth}{5ex}
\setlength{\cftphotographindent}{0ex}
\newlength{\photographlen}% a pre photo  title length
\settowidth{\photographlen}{\bfseries\cftphotographpresnum} % the word Photograph~
\addtolength{\photographlen}{\cftphotographnumwidth}
\renewcommand{\cftphotographnumwidth}{\photographlen}
\renewcommand{\cftphotographaftersnum}{.}

\begin{document}    
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \listoffigures  
    \listofphotographs
    
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{First dummy figure}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Second dummy figure}
    \end{figure}
    
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    \begin{photograph}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{First dummy photo}
    \end{photograph}
    \begin{photograph}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Second dummy photo}
    \end{photograph}
    
\end{document}
```